# List changes but React re-render the same one

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-redux

my goal is sort an array of objects using redux.
So, my react-app starts getting the objects from a server updating the redux store and render the list of items.
Then, clicking a button my reducer update the store with the same array but sorted and returns the new state to my container-component that will pass the new props to the "list-Component" causing a re-render of this component.
Now i expect that the list of items re-rendered will be sorted but the list is the same as before...
Why? Any ideas?

here the code:

**App.js** (container-component)

```
class App extends Component {

    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.sortBy(GET_LIST);
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div className="App">
                <Nav sortByDate={() => {
                    this.props.sortBy(SORT_BY_DATE)
                }} sortByLikes={() => {
                    this.props.sortBy(SORT_BY_LIKES)
                }}/>
                <Items comments={this.props.comments}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        comments: state.comments
    }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        sortBy: (action) => {
            dispatch(sortBy(action));
        }
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

**CommentList.js**

```
class ListItems extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }


    getComments() {
        return (this.props.comments.map(function (object) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(object));
            return <Item numLikes={object.num_like} id={object.id} comment={object.comment} date={object.date}
                         sender={object.sender}/>
        }));
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <Container>
                <Row>
                    <Col lg={2} md={1} xs={0}/>
                    <Col lg={8} md={10} xs={12}>
                        {console.log("RENDER")}
                        {console.log(JSON.stringify(this.props.comments))}
                        {this.getComments()}
                    </Col>
                    <Col lg={2} md={16} xs={0}/>
                </Row>
            </Container>
        );
    }
}

export default ListItems;
```

**Reducer.js**

```
const listReducer = (state = {
    comments: []
}, action) => {
    function toDate(dateStr) {
        const [day, month, year] = dateStr.split("/") return new Date(year, month - 1, day)
    }

    function commentSortedByDate(comments) {
        comments.sort(function(a, b) {
            return toDate(b.date) - toDate(a.date);
        }) return [...comments];
    }

    function commentSortedByLikes(comments) {
        comments.sort(function(a, b) {
            return parseInt(b.num_like) - parseInt(a.num_like);
        }) return [...comments];
    }
    switch (action.type) {
        case SORT_BY_DATE:
            console.log("sort by date");
            state = {...state, comments: commentSortedByDate(state.comments)
            }
            break;
        case SORT_BY_LIKES:
            console.log("sort by likes");
            state = {...state, comments: commentSortedByLikes(state.comments)
            }
            break;
        case GET_LIST:
            state = {...state, comments: action.payload
            }
            break;
    }
    return state;
};
export default listReducer;
```

Comment: Please post the reducer's code

Comment: Please add your reducer's code. Everything seems to be right in the code posted above.

Comment: Reducer.js Added!

Answer (score 0):

You are mutating the state...
Instead of

```
state = {...state, comments: commentSortedByDate(state.comments)
```

You should write

```
return {...state, comments: commentSortedByDate(state.comments)
```

Comment: (I missed to update my reducer here with `[...comments]` ) and it's the same thing if i mutate the state or not

Comment: `return {...state, xxx}` and `state={...state, xxx}` are the same if the xxx content is returned  `[...xxx]` by a function..
But muted or not the list rendered is always the same as first